# setup-install magento 2. Type Error occurred when creating object

Tags: magento, installation, magento2

I'm having a problem when I install new Magento 2 on my ubuntu. I got an error when I run the command:

```
sudo bin/magento setup:install 
--admin-firstname="zzz" 
--admin-lastname="zzz" 
--admin-email="zzz@gmail.com" 
--admin-user="admin" 
--admin-password="admin123" 
--db-name="zzzdb" 
--db-user="root" 
--db-password=""
```

Error:
[Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlsYX.png)

I've consulted the solutions but it seems to be creating a new project, not installing. And I tried `rm -rf generated/`, `chmod -R 777 generated/`. But it doesn't work  =((

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type Error means that Object Manager can't instantiate given object due to invalid parameters. The class \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime has a dependency on TimezoneInterface

```php
public function __construct(TimezoneInterface $localeDate)
```

Which is implemented by
`Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Timezone`
which then depends on
`Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Intl\DateFormatterFactory`
that requires PHP-intl extension.
(in the constructor instantiates IntlDateFormatter)

```php
$formatter = new \IntlDateFormatter(
    $locale,
    $dateStyle,
    $timeStyle,
    $timeZone
);
```

My guess is that you haven't installed intl extension for PHP.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php

You can get more verbose input by providing -vvv as the command argument.

Answer (score 0):

That is very simple, since \DateTime object always contains a timezone, it is possible to translate it into UTC at any time. As you see, it does call internally \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime to convert time into a text representation.

Ideally, as with any other modern PHP ORM, you should be able to specify the \DateTime object, and the rest of how it is stored should be processed by the library itself. So, it's very well known that during installation, the PHP intl extension is missing.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if all module are available/installed in your system by run command in your magento2 root directory:

```
composer install
```

if this give some error then read error there mentioned php-missing modules.

Then you can install them by :

```
sudo apt-get php{php version}-{module name}

example
sudo apt-get php8.1-intl
```